# Spring & JUnit: Configure using xml, not annotations

Tags: java, xml, spring, junit

So, with Spring, I prefer xml over annotation. It's just a personal preference, I like having the xml docs unifying my spring config data.

Anyway, I'm working on a JUnit test case for database access. My first time using the spring-test library. I'm trying to use dependency injection to inject the StudentDao bean into this class below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration ({"classpath:/test-context.xml"})
public class StudentDaoTest extends TestCase {

private StudentDao studentDao;

public StudentDao getStudentDao() {
    return studentDao;
}

public void setStudentDao(StudentDao studentDao) {
    this.studentDao = studentDao;
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void test(){
    //This ends up printing null, identifying the problem
    if(studentDao == null){
        System.out.println("Null");
    }

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setFirstName("First");
    studentDao.insertStudent(student);
}
```

}

The thing is, as you can guess from the comment, is this isn't working. The test-context.xml file starts up, and the other context file it imports also starts up, as I can see from the log, so it's not that the program can't find the file. Somehow the xml doc that I have is just not configuring the bean properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"> 

<import resource="data-context.xml"/>

<bean id="studentDaoTest" class="io.craigmiller160.schedule.persist.StudentDaoTest">
    <property name="studentDao" ref="studentDao"/>
</bean>
```

I discovered that if I used the @Autowired annotation on studentDao it does work. The thing is, I don't use annotations anywhere else in the program, and I want to maintain consistency. Honestly, I would prefer to avoid using @ContextConfiguration too, but I don't think I'll be able to do that.

So, I'm looking for help making this injection work with just xml. I know, I'm being picky, but I like my consistency, as I said.

Thanks in advance.

PS. the full filepath of the files is:

StudentDaoTest: src/test/java/io/myname/schedule/persist/StudentDaoTest
test-context.xml: src/test/resources/test-context.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Spring annotations why use them ?

```
public class MyTest {

  private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
  @Before
  public void initApplicationContext() {
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("...");
  }
  @After
  public void closeApplicationContext() {
    if (context != null) {
      context.close();
      context = null;
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    context.getBean(Object.class);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Will that let me use the @Transactional JTA annotations? It's the only one I want. I can't get that to work without using the other annotations in this test class.

Comment: No `@Transactional` support is provided by `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`. Just to be sure. The only constraints is about Spring configuration consistency across your project(s) ? If so, keep using `@ContextConfiguraiton` (it is part of `spring-test`) and good old [ApplicationContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-aware) and [other aware interfaces](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aware-list)

Answer (score -1):

Inject application context and work with it as you like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration ({"classpath:/test-context.xml"})
public class StudentDaoTest extends TestCase {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;
```

Actually the definition of the studentDaoTest bean has no effect on the test just because there is no such functional in the testing framework.